# How to Keep cookie without changing browser setting using jQuery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, browser

Is there any way to keep cookie using `jQuery` or `javascript` without changing browser settings ?

EDIT

```
    private void RememberCookiesInformation()
    {            
        Response.Cookies.Clear()           
        HttpCookie RememberDivCookie = new HttpCookie("RememberCookiesInformation");
        RememberDivCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);            
        Response.Cookies.Add(RememberDivCookie);
    }
```

Here my cookie is `RememberCookiesInformation`.

Any solution?

Comment: it seems you are creating session cookie set the expire time to cookie should work

Comment: I m setting expiration time still firefox deleting it but i dont want to change firefox setting

Comment: You have to show your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use expire value. And your cookie will not destroy after browser restart.

In the following example the cookie will reset after 7 days.

**Example:**

```
                        HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("ArticleView" + contentID);
                        aCookie.Values["Article_Content_ID"] =contentID.ToString();
                        aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```

Comment: I have tried this but in firefox setting it clears cookies after closing but i dont want to chande firefox setting